# Adding running sum in group by date in new row

Tags: c#, system.linq.dynamic, syncfusion-blazor

I'm working Syncfusion DocIO with creating tables in .docx with some props and can't create row with group by date
=> on every new year I need new row with running sum.
I already create sum row, but this row returns all sum for additional props (columns),
so all I need is for each year in new row running sum.

My example:

| Months | Anuity | InterestPaid | PrincipalPaid | BalanceDue | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 84,69 | 2,50 | 82,19 | 917,81 | 2021/11/12 |
| 2 | 84,69 | 2,29 | 82,40 | 835,41 | 2021/12/12 |
| Sum for year 2021 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 84,69 | 2,09 | 82,61 | 752,80 | 2022/1/12 |
| 4 | 84,69 | 1,88 | 82,81 | 669,99 | 2022/2/12 |
| 5 | 84,69 | 1,67 | 83,02 | 586,97 | 2022/3/12 |
| 6 | 84,69 | 1,47 | 83,23 | 503,75 | 2022/4/12 |
| 7 | 84,69 | 1,26 | 83,43 | 420,31 | 2022/5/12 |
| 8 | 84,69 | 1,05 | 83,64 | 336,67 | 2022/6/12 |
| 9 | 84,69 | 0,84 | 83,85 | 252,82 | 2022/7/12 |
| 10 | 84,69 | 0,63 | 84,06 | 168,75 | 2022/8/12 |
| 11 | 84,69 | 0,42 | 84,27 | 84,48 | 2022/9/12 |
| 12 | 84,69 | 0,21 | 84,48 | 0,00 | 2022/10/12 |
| Sum for year 2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sum all | 1016,32 | 16,32 | 1000,00 |  |  |

My code:

```
        int i = 1;
        
        foreach (var amortizationData in aAmortizationPlanLoanPayment)
        {
            WTableRow tableRow = tableAmortizationData.AddRow(true);

            tableRow.Cells[0].AddParagraph().AppendText(i.ToString());
            tableRow.Cells[1].AddParagraph().AppendText(amortizationData.Anuity.ToString());
            tableRow.Cells[2].AddParagraph().AppendText(amortizationData.InterestPaid.ToString());
            tableRow.Cells[3].AddParagraph().AppendText(amortizationData.PrincipalPaid.ToString());
            tableRow.Cells[4].AddParagraph().AppendText(amortizationData.BalanceDue.ToString());
            tableRow.Cells[5].AddParagraph().AppendText(amortizationData.Date.AddMonths(aAmortizationPlanLoanPaymentData.Moratorium).ToString("yyyy/M/dd"));
            i++;
            
            if (amortizationData.Date.Month == 12)
            {
                    WTableRow YearSumrow = tableAmortizationData.AddRow(true);

                    WTableCell cell1 = YearSumrow.Cells[0];

                    var sumYearIWTextRange = cell1.AddParagraph().AppendText($"Sum for year {amortizationData.Date.Year}");

                sumYearIWTextRange = YearSumrow.Cells[1].AddParagraph().AppendText(); // need here running sum inside appendText();

                sumYearIWTextRange = YearSumrow.Cells[2].AddParagraph().AppendText(); // need here running sum inside appendText();

                sumYearIWTextRange = YearSumrow.Cells[3].AddParagraph().AppendText(); // need here running sum inside appendText();
            }

            if (amortizationData.BalanceDue == 0.00)
            {
                WTableRow LastYearRow = tableAmortizationData.AddRow(true);

                WTableCell cellLastYear = LastYearRow.Cells[0];

                var sumLastYearIWTextRange = cellLastYear.AddParagraph().AppendText($"Sum for year {amortizationData.Date.Year}");

                sumLastYearIWTextRange = LastYearRow.Cells[1].AddParagraph().AppendText(); // need here running sum inside appendText();

                sumLastYearIWTextRange = LastYearRow.Cells[2].AddParagraph().AppendText(); // need here running sum inside appendText();

                sumLastYearIWTextRange = LastYearRow.Cells[3].AddParagraph().AppendText(); // need here running sum inside appendText();
            }
        }

        
        WTableRow tableRowSum = tableAmortizationData.AddRow(true);
        WTableCell cell = tableRowSum.Cells[0];

        var totalIWTextRage = cell.AddParagraph().AppendText("Sum all");

        var totalAmountIWTextRage = tableRowSum.Cells[1].AddParagraph().AppendText(aAmortizationPlanLoanPayment.Sum(p => p.Anuity).ToString());

        totalAmountIWTextRage = tableRowSum.Cells[2].AddParagraph().AppendText(aAmortizationPlanLoanPayment.Sum(p => p.InterestPaid).ToString());

        totalAmountIWTextRage = tableRowSum.Cells[3].AddParagraph().AppendText(aAmortizationPlanLoanPayment.Sum(p => p.PrincipalPaid).ToString());
```

Comment: "I already create sum row with Linq, but ...." Where is the LINQ ? Why can you not create this sum using Linq ? What did you try ? No one can tell why it failed, because you do not share what you tried....

Comment: Taking out the irrelevant font size and bold lines would make that code a lot more readable for us; perhaps you should move those codes to a generator method to clean it up for real too

Comment: All in, it looks like the sort of thing I wouldn't use LINQ for; use a foreach loop instead. Linq is a hammer, but not every problem is a nail

Answer (score 0):

If you had a bunch of numbers (already grouped and summed to distinct dates, but doesn't have to be);

```
(DateTime D, int V)[] rows = new [] {
  (new(1999, 12, 1), 111), 
  (new(2000, 1, 1), 222), 
  (new(2000, 2, 1), 333), 
  (new(2000, 3, 1), 444),
  (new(2001, 1, 1), 555)
}
```

Then sure, you could do your running sum with LINQ:

```
foreach(var row in rows){
  var runSum = rows.Where(r => r.D <= row.D).Sum(r => r.V);
}
```

But it's a lot more resource wasteful than just keeping a variable:

```
var runSum = 0;
foreach(var row in rows){
  runSum += row.V;
}
```

If you want your running sum to start over from time to time just remember the previous row (naturally your rows need to be in order):

```
var prevRow = rows[0];
var runSum = 0;
foreach(var row in rows){

  if(prevRow.D.Year != row.D.Year)
    runSum = 0;

  runSum += row.V;
}
```

Do your output above the line where you increment the runSum if you don't want the current line value to appear in the total, or below it if you do

Comment: _"But it's a lot more resource wasteful than just keeping a variable"_ are we going to have that discussion? Your statement is quite opinionated. Many argue that the LINQ expression better states intent, and less error-prone (e.g. the for loop is missing the filter -> select/if statement). The potential loss in performance is often not critical, while the maintainability is improved.

Comment: *Your statement is quite opinionated* - no; it's a fact. Having a list of numbers one thousand long, and incrementing a variable **one thousand times** is less resource intensive than incrementing a variable **five hundred thousand** times

Comment: I think we're on a different wavelength. I thought you were talking about the general case of LINQ being less performant than a for-loop. Apparently you are not, or are you? I find it hard to compare your code examples, as each one seems to do something different.

Comment: Oh, yes some confusion has possibly arisen; when I was observing a resource burn it was comparing something like the first code block of doing a LINQ sum of all previous values on every loop iteration, which is O((n^2)/2), with the simple increment (second code block) of an outside-loop var which would be O(n).